# How do I get hex codes to work with tkinter text boxes? The regular colors like "red", "yellow" etc works. But not hex

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

OS: Windows 10

This is my "texter", it is used to print letter for letter at certain speeds. It takes the text to print, and a text color as arguments. This works perfectly if i write - texter("Hello there", "red")

```
global charpos
charpos = 1.0
def texter(inserted_text, text_color = "white"):
    global charpos, text
    text.configure(state='disabled')
    charpos = (charpos + 1)
    for char in inserted_text:
        text.configure(state='normal')
        text.insert(charpos, f"{char}", text_color)
        charpos += 1.0
        text.configure(state='disabled')
        waithere(10)
```

However it stops working and only prints white text when I do something like - texter("Hello there", "orange2")

And "orange2" should be a supported color in tkinter, right?

For instance, this code works perfectly:

```
texter("[Freya]: ", "yellow")
    texter("Well you don't have a choice!\n\n")
```

While these examples do not work, and just prints the white text:

```
texter("[Freya]: ", "snow")
    texter("Well you don't have a choice!\n\n")

texter("[Freya]: ", "#8E44AD")
    texter("Well you don't have a choice!\n\n")
```

This is my first python project, started learning two or three weeks ago so please excuse any other mistakes in my code. Does anyone have any good ideas to why the most basic colors work, but the tkinter "advanced" colors do not, and hex values do not?

I should also mention the hex colors and advanced colors DO WORK when applied to the tkinter main window, or background colors of the textbox I am using, but not on the actual text inside it. I believe my texter function is the problem, but I cannot figure out what it is since it is working with regular colors such as "yellow", "blue", "red", "black" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know what that last argument to `insert` is? it's tag name, what you should do, is then configure that tag to the color you want, so basically just add `text.tag_config(text_color, foreground=text_color)` at the end of the function, also I hope that you understand that you don't need to insert characters individually and you can just do `text.insert(charpos, inserted_text, ...)` and then just do `charpos += len(inserted_text)`, so the function now should look like:

```py
charpos = 1.0
def texter(inserted_text, text_color = "white"):
    global charpos
    charpos += 1
    text.configure(state="normal")
    text.insert(charpos, inserted_text, text_color)
    text.tag_config(text_color, foreground=text_color)
    text.configure(state="disabled")
    charpos += len(inserted_text)
    waithere(10)
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you. I blundered and forgot that the insert uses text.tag_config to configure foreground colors. I know that I could use charpos += len(inserted_text), and just insert the inserted_text as a whole, but for "style" I wanted every letter to pop in one at a time.

Comment: @RobinWright oh that's what `waithere` is for, cool cool, so like typewriter style, nice

Comment: Yep! Took a while day figuring out why time.sleep didnt work in tkinter, but holy I am learning a lot. Once again, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

The first is the declaration of `charpos` as a float. `tkinter.Text` widget uses a string of two integers connected by a dot. (1.0 = row 1. column 0). There are methods for calculating cursor position in `Text` widget.

The second problem is the use of `color_text` to change `foreground` color. You need to use `text.tag_config(color_text, ...)` to declare color_text as a tagname.

Here is a code snippet that demonstrates.

```py
import time
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(window)
text.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)

charpos = '1.0'

def waithere(n):
    text.update()
    while n > 0:
        n = n - 0.00005

def texter(inserted_text, text_color = "white"):
    text.configure(state='disabled')
    charpos = text.index("end")
    # inform text of new color tag
    text.tag_config(text_color, foreground = text_color)

    for char in inserted_text:
        text.configure(state='normal')
        text.insert(charpos, f"{char}", text_color)
        charpos = text.index(charpos + " + 1c")
        text.configure(state='disabled')
        waithere(10)

# showing off with multiple colors on same line.
for a in range(3):
    texter("Hello ", "black")
    texter("i'm a ", "blue")
    texter("robot\n", "red") # linefeed here controls text layout
```